# How to get access to the other similar modules in Omnet++

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I am using multiple Adhoc Hosts in my Network and I need pointers to all adhoc hosts present in the network in my UDPApp.cc file.
If I use getParentModule(),I get access to only the module on which that application is called.
So if there are 3 hosts-> host1,host2 and host3.
I get access to only host1, host 2 , host 3 but that separately.I want pointers to all 3 at the same time.

Or a pointer to the network which contains them.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `getModuleByPath(path)` from any module to look for a module with indicated name and path in the whole simulation network.
 An example (assuming that there are 10 hosts):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
    char buf[20];
    sprintf(buf, "host%d", i);
    cModule * mod = getModuleByPath(buf);
    if (mod != nullptr) {
       // ... 
       // now mod contains the pointer to another host's module
    } else {
        EV << "No module " << buf << endl;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Assuming that every AdHoc host has a submodule called `manetrouting` a more generic solution may be used:

```
cModule *network = cSimulation::getActiveSimulation()->getSystemModule();
for (SubmoduleIterator it(network); !it.end(); ++it) {
    cModule * mod = *it;
    if (mod->getSubmodule("manetrouting") != nullptr) {
        // check whether it is the same host
        if (this != mod && getParentModule() != mod) {
           EV << "Host " << mod->getName() << " is anther AdHoc host (not itself)" << endl;
        }
    } 
}
```

An additional condition has been added to omit the host involving this code in results.

Comment: So it will have to be hardcoded,isnt it? Like one should know the names of other modules in the network. Is there anyway we could simply get a list of other modules or is this is the best we can do?                                   Thank you for your reply.

Comment: One should precise which element distinguish AdHoc host from another modules in the network. It could be a name, or an internal module, or additional annotation, which *is not present* inside module of another type. I have extended my answer assuming that each AdHoc host has a submodule `manetrouting`. If it is not true in your model, provide a definition of your Adhoc host.

Comment: As a side note. If this has answered your question, you should 'accept' it. Accepting an answer have good consequences for all future users who may have the same problem, not to mention that in reinforces the people who gave the correct answer.

Comment: This design is so terrible on so many levels ... It would have been much, much cleaner to have a getter that takes in a regex to filter out components. Who on Earth came up with this ****? Each module should have a context in which it can access all submodules. SMH

Answer (score 0):

Really good answer! I was having problems using getSubmodule, instead after using the suggested iteration I was able to find the module. from @Jerzy D.

here my code:

```
cModule* test = this->getParentModule();
for (SubmoduleIterator it(test); !it.end(); ++it) {
    cModule * mod = *it;
    EV << "Module : " << mod->getName() << endl;
    std::string mod_name = mod->getName();
    std::string x = "wlan";
    if (x.compare(mod_name) == 0) {
        // check whether it is the same host
        test3 = mod;
        EV << "Module : " << mod->getName() << endl;
        cModule *test2 = test1->getSubmodule("mac");
    }
}
```